# How can I connect two sqlite databases across java desktop and android applications?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am using sqlite as my android database. The android app communicates with my java app which is also using sqlite database. How can I connect these two databases.
I need to send data from android app to desktop app and viceversa.

Comment: As far I know sqlite is serverless. So how can I create a server?

Comment: This site is for very specific programming questions on a narrow topic. For discussion, visit a site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Web Services or HttpUrlConnection to connect with databases and have to manage Android and Desktop data separately.  make web api calls to get latest data from Desktop Database

Comment: Sqlite is server less, then you have to create another Master database on server and then need to connect that database with desktop and Android App Both